# Arduino 1.6.1 installation

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, arduino

I unpacked the Arduino archive.

I have jdk, jre installed properly.

When I am trying to launch Arduino 1.6.1 IDE I get the following error and I have no idea where to start from to solve it.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still consider myself a noobie, but here's how I am running Arduino 1.6.3 (on Ubuntu 14.10 using a 5-year old **32-BIT** HP computer. FORGIVE ME if this is very simplistic, but I spend HOURS sometimes trying to figure out what some people mean by "open a terminal and type %t/go -get run/play then you are on a rocketship to the moon!" SOOOO... this covers A LOT of basics you may already know (or not, honestly, I barely understand what I'm describing below)

1. I downloaded the zip file arduino-nightly-linux32.tar.xz from here (YOU MAY NEED 64-bit. Ask your computer what it is: 32-bit or 64-bit):
   https://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software to my desktop.
2. I double clicked the arduino-nightly-linux.tar.xz icon and it opened a window that showed the .tar.xz file. I clicked the the extract button at the top of the window and extracted the contents of the arduino-nightly-linux.tar.xz archive to my desktop.
3. Once it was extracted, I could see and open the folder on my desktop (with all my other stuff), but could not run Arduino from there. I opened a terminal (Crtl+Alt+T)... Note: capitalization matters in the terminal and depends on what YOUR machine calls the files/locations you are using...
4. I typed: `cd Desktop` and it gave me this prompt: jay@jay:~/Desktop$
5. I Typed on the line after the $ `ls` --  I click Enter and it LISTED every file and folder on my desktop.
6. I could see Arduino-nightly in the list (it was blue for some reason).  If you DON'T see it in the list, you are in the WRONG directory and you need to "cd" to the directory it IS IN.
7. then I typed on the line after Desktop$ `cd Arduino-nightly` and it gave me this:

`jay@jay:~/Desktop/arduino-nightly$`

8. after the $ on that line, I typed `./arduino`
9. ...and Arduino IDE interface window thing 1.6.3 came up. I programmed a couple of stepper motors I had just bought on Ebay!

I hope that helped.